# Python + pexpect - How to establish a ssh connection?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I've been trying to establish an ssh connection via Python + pexpect, but I can't send the lines that I want.

I think it's certainly a syntax problem, but I don't know where it is occurring.

```
#! /usr/bin/python # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import pexpect
import sys



child = pexpect.spawn ("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"ssh -X user@localhost; exec bash\"'")
child.expect ("user@localhost\"''s password.*:\"'")
child.sendline ('xxyyzz')

print "OK"
```

The problem is that the password 'xxyyzz' never appears on the terminal, so I think the `child.sendline` doesn't work and is a syntax problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the input to the `gnome-terminal` process here. That won't work, because it's `ssh` (technically, `bash`, but bash's `stdin` is also `ssh`'s) that need that input, not `gnome-terminal`.

---

Regardless, you're probably going to have a hard time ever getting this to work reliably. You should probably consider using a Python SSH library.

Good choices include:

- [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) - low level Python SSH library
- [Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric) - higher level library (that uses Paramiko under the hood)

Comment: Ok so how do I include Paramiko and include de pass in the ssh's input stdin ? Could you give me an example ?

Comment: @user3421938 You should check the Paramiko documentation. You can start here: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestion but i'd prefer to use pexpect. I found the way :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
# my ssh command line
child=pexpect.spawn('ssh username@server uname -a')
i=child.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
if i==0:
   print "I say yes"
   child.sendline('yes')
i=child.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
if i==1:
   print "I give password",
   child.sendline("xxxx")
   child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
elif i==2:
   print "I either got key or connection timeout"
pass
print child.before # print out the result
```

Regards !!!